# How can I find the average of every next 4 values in a single column (Dataframe) and put every average found in a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

[[image]

This is the data where I need to find the average prices of Germany/luxemborg for every 4 hours as they are given in every hour and store it into a dataframe. I am having a lot of troubles in this because even after averaging it the new column would have less indexes than the original (8760) prbably something around 2200. Please help me :(

Comment: Could you share a little more, with text not images, about the problem and what you have tried? What data types are you working with? From the image, it looks like you have two columns for your date and time data.

Answer (score 0):

First, always add a dummy so someone who wants to help can just add it to their environment.

Second, you want rolling function. Rolling can roll back across a specified number of rows or a specified time period.

Let's try with the number of rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ["12 AM", "1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM","4 AM","5 AM"],
                  "number": [50.87, 48.19, 44.68, 42.92, 40.39, 40.2]})

# since your rows are already 1 hours apart
# 4 rows for 4 hours

df["avg"] = df.number.rolling(4).mean()

    Time  number      avg
0  12 AM   50.87      NaN
1   1 AM   48.19      NaN
2   2 AM   44.68      NaN
3   3 AM   42.92  46.6650
4   4 AM   40.39  44.0450
5   5 AM   40.20  42.0475
```

Please be noted that when there is not enough (4) rows to calculate, it results in Na. But what if your rows are not 1 hour uniformly apart, then the function will still calculate the meann of previous 4 rows, but it will not be 4 hours average for some rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ["12 AM", "1 AM", "2 AM", "5 AM","6 AM","7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM"],
                  "number": [50.87, 48.19, 44.68, 42.92, 40.39, 40.2, 41.27, 44.88]})

df["avg"] = df.number.rolling(4).mean()

    Time  number      avg
0  12 AM   50.87      NaN
1   1 AM   48.19      NaN
2   2 AM   44.68      NaN
3   5 AM   42.92  46.6650 # notice 5AM but same value with previous 4AM
4   6 AM   40.39  44.0450
5   7 AM   40.20  42.0475
6   8 AM   41.27  41.1950
7   9 AM   44.88  41.6850
```

Instead, Rolling can roll back across time. But for that we need a couple preparations, such as changing column type to datetime and setting it as index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ["12 AM", "1 AM", "2 AM", "5 AM","6 AM","7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM"],
                  "number": [50.87, 48.19, 44.68, 42.92, 40.39, 40.2, 41.27, 44.88]})

df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%I %p")
df.set_index(['Time'], inplace =True)

                     number        avg
Time                                  
1900-01-01 00:00:00   50.87  50.870000
1900-01-01 01:00:00   48.19  49.530000
1900-01-01 02:00:00   44.68  47.913333
1900-01-01 03:00:00   42.92  46.665000
1900-01-01 04:00:00   40.39  44.045000
1900-01-01 05:00:00   40.20  42.047500
```

Ignore the years, Pandas defaulted it back to 1900 since our column does not have it. Now check for uneven time intervals.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ["12 AM", "1 AM", "2 AM", "5 AM","6 AM","7 AM"],
                  "number": [50.87, 48.19, 44.68, 42.92, 40.39, 40.2]})

df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%I %p")
df.set_index(['Time'], inplace =True)

                     number        avg
Time                                  
1900-01-01 00:00:00   50.87  50.870000
1900-01-01 01:00:00   48.19  49.530000
1900-01-01 02:00:00   44.68  47.913333
1900-01-01 05:00:00   42.92  43.800000
1900-01-01 06:00:00   40.39  41.655000
1900-01-01 07:00:00   40.20  41.170000
1900-01-01 08:00:00   41.27  41.195000
1900-01-01 09:00:00   44.88  41.685000
```

Notice, rolling across time does not leave Na values because when it does not have enough (4) time steps before, it finds the average among what's existing (such as (a+b+c)/3, (a+b)/2 and a/1). So, We can add a parameter called *min_period*.

```
df["avg"] = df.number.rolling('4h', min_periods = 4).mean()

                     number     avg
Time                               
1900-01-01 00:00:00   50.87     NaN
1900-01-01 01:00:00   48.19     NaN
1900-01-01 02:00:00   44.68     NaN
1900-01-01 05:00:00   42.92     NaN
1900-01-01 06:00:00   40.39     NaN
1900-01-01 07:00:00   40.20     NaN
1900-01-01 08:00:00   41.27  41.195
1900-01-01 09:00:00   44.88  41.685
```